# Scala - How can we create class instance of same class?

Tags: scala

I'm working to create an array of instances of the class in itself.

```
class A (arg: Int) {
    var a1 = new Array[A] (arg)
    ....
}
```

declaring it this way gives "java.lang.NullPointerException" during run-time. Is there any way to remove this exception?

Comment: Could you please provide the stacktrace and more code, e.g. the line where the `NullPointerException` occurs. `new Array[A](len)` will create an array holding len NullPointers which are "preserved" for instances of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you are trying to access elements of array a1 later in your code. There you get your exception.

I've prepared small chunk of code to demonstrate it:

```
class A (arg: Int) {
    var a1=new Array[A] (arg)   
    def giveMeException(){
      println(a1(0).a1.length)
    }
}
object Program  extends App {
    val noExceptionA = new A(2);
    noExceptionA.a1(0) = new A(0);
    noExceptionA.a1(1) = new A(0);
    val exceptionA = new A(2);

    // Will print 0
    noExceptionA.giveMeException();

    // Will throw  java.lang.NullPointerException
    exceptionA.giveMeException();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to what you want to achieve by this code:

```
var a1 = new Array[A] (arg)
```

I guess you want an array of `arg` elements of type `A`, but what theses elements should be? By default they are `null` (or `0` for primitive types). Later you access this array (e.g. `a1(0)` and obviously you get `NullPointerException`.

So you should *fill* the array after creating it. Here is the first approach:

```
class A (arg: Int) {
    var al = Array.fill(arg)(new A(arg))  //WRONG!
}
```

Note that `Array.fill(3)("Foo")` result in `["Foo", "Foo", "Foo"]` array. Do you see the problem here? When creating `new A(arg)` you are recursively calling `new A(arg)`. The loop never ends. Again I don't know what you want to achieve, so here is a working, correct sample:

```
class A (arg: Int) {
    var al = Array.fill(arg)(new A(arg - 1))
}
```

Calling `new A(3)` will create an array of `[A(2), A(2), A(2)]`. In turns each call to `A(2)` will create `[A(1), A(1)]`. The recurson ends on `new A(0)` which creates an empty array.